# i want to access dropdownlist control which is inside radpageview of telerik control in my code behind file

Tags: asp.net, telerik

i am facing problem with **telerik tab** control.

i have two tabs which i have created using **telerik tab control** that is **radtabstrip.**

now i have one **dropdownlist control** which is inside **radpageview of radmultipage**.

now can any one provide me syntax of how to access **drop downlist**  which is inside **radpageview** of

**radmultipage**???

i have tried this but facing error:
radpageview1.drodownlist1.item.selecteditem;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FindControl() like with any other nested control (e.g., a Panel). Here is an example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadDropDownList rddl = RadPageView2.FindControl("RadDropDownList1") as RadDropDownList;
    rddl.Visible = false;
}
```

assuming your structure looks like this (whether it is generated from the code-behind is irrelevant, you only need to recreate it early enough):

```
        <telerik:RadTabStrip runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="first"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="second"></telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
        <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1">
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Width="100%">
                PageView
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Width="100%">
                <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="RadDropDownList1"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Comment: thank u so so so so much 4 ur kind help.i realy appreciate that.thank u once again